# Laravel Nayjest datagrid pagination not working from second page

Tags: laravel-5

Below is my controller function and my table name is User_deposit.if i dont use condition with my table i can get exact output for all pages.but if place condition in my query  then i can get result for the first page only.

Controller Function:

```
  public function admin_user_dep_report(){

    $id = Input::get('name_id');

     $cfg = (new GridConfig())
        ->setDataProvider(new EloquentDataProvider(\App\User_deposit::query()->where('user_id',$id)))
        ->setName('user_deposits_page')
       ->setPageSize(5)

        ->setColumns([
              new IdFieldConfig,

            (new FieldConfig)
             ->setName('amount')
            # will be displayed in table heder
            ->setLabel('Amount')

            ,

            (new FieldConfig)
            ->setName('agent_verified')
            # will be displayed in table heder
            ->setLabel('Agent Verified')
            ->setCallback(function ($val,$row) {

                $user = $row->getSrc();
                return  $user->getAgent->first_name;

            })




        ]);
   $grid = new Grid($cfg);
    $grid = $grid->render();



return view('admin.user_deposit_reports')->with('cfg',$grid);
}
```

View File:

```
   <div class="container">

       <?php echo $cfg; ?>


</div>
```

Note:
My table has more than 20 entries i am getting  records for the first page and null records for the 2nd 3rd ... pages

Answer (score 1):

In my experience using non alphabetic characters in the setName property and making it too long doesn't work. I have seen the behaviour you're describing when I put a space in my name variable.

Try changing the following:

```
$cfg = (new GridConfig())
    ->setDataProvider(new EloquentDataProvider(\App\User_deposit::query()->where('user_id',$id)))
    ->setName('user_deposits_page')
   ->setPageSize(5)
```

To something like:

```
$cfg = (new GridConfig())
    ->setDataProvider(new EloquentDataProvider(\App\User_deposit::query()->where('user_id',$id)))
    ->setName('userdeposits')
   ->setPageSize(5)
```

Also, try putting:

```
use App\User_deposit;
```

At the top of your file and then change:

```
\App\User_deposit
```

to:

```
User_deposit
```

This makes the code more readable in my opinion.